# How on earth do you get the return value from an MVC2 checkbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, checkbox, html-helper

I have a checkbox on one of my forms.  And unfortunately, I cant't seem to figure out how to get the value out of the thing on the server side (my controlller).  How in sam hill do you do that?  It seems like you have to do a check for when the form ellement if not false?
How do you do this?

**Adding some addition information**
        if ((formCollection["popID"] != null) && (formCollection["StartDate"] != null) && (formCollection["EndDate"] != null) && (formCollection["sendAnyway"] != null))
                {
                    string popId = formCollection["popID"];
                    if (formCollection["StartDate"] != "")
                    {
                        startDate = DateTime.Parse(formCollection["StartDate"]);
                    }

```
                if (formCollection["EndDate"] != "")
                {
                    endDate = DateTime.Parse(formCollection["EndDate"]);
                }

                Boolean sendAnyway = Boolean.Parse(formCollection["sendAnyway"]);

                if (client.ProcessGetABBYPopulation(popId, startDate, endDate, sendAnyway) == false)
                {
                    return PutToQError("Error placing message on Queue");
                }
                else
                {

                    //return Success("You successfully placed a message on the Queue");
                    return RedirectToAction("Home", "Home");
                }
            }
```

Here is my view (where I have a checkbox)

```
     <%:Html.Label("Reprocess patients already sent during this timeframe?") %>
     <%:Html.CheckBox("sendAnyway") %>
```

**Update 2**

Checking my return value it returns, "true,false"
what kind of sense does that make?

Comment: we'll likely need to see your controller action, are you taking a model?  or the form fields as a parameter?

Comment: Please post example of code what you have so we can provide some solution to your problem... it is difficult to help as there can be more than one scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using a strongly typed view model, you're probably doing something like this:

```
 <% Html.CheckBox("someName") %>
```

In which case, you can access it when you POST it to your server like so:

```
 public ActionResult SomeMethod(string someName) // Bound via name on the parameter
 {
     string value = Request.Form["someName"]; // Or pulled from the Form collection
     // someValue / value = "1" or whatever your checkbox value was, IF SELECTED. 
     // If unselected, it's NULL. 
 }
```

If you're using a strongly typed view model, it's available the same way:

```
 <% Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsSet) %>
```

And then accessed like:

```
 public ActionResult SomeMethod(MySampleViewModel vm)
 {
      vm.IsSet; // true if selected, false if not
      string request = Request.Form["IsSet"];
      // request = value of your checkbox, NULL otherwise. 
 }
```